# Rabbitmq/Pika - get a consumer list of a given queue in python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I would like to find a way to get a list of the consumers that are connected to a given queue in rabbitmq
in python.
need a script that returns a list of the consumer that are connected to a queue(for me its devices)
the ip and name.

Thanks for the help!

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
queue_state = channel.queue_declare(
    queue='some_Queue', passive=True,  durable=True)
```

I found a way to get the consumers count, but not the list of the consumer itself.. so still no solution:

```
consumers = queue_state.method.consumer_count
print(consumers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the monotoring APIs:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

api_queues = 'http://' + host_ip + ':' + api_port + '/api/queues/%2F/'+queue_name
res = requests.get(api_queues, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(login, password))
res_json = res.json()
# Number of consumers
number_of_consumers= len(res_json['consumer_details'])
```

Please not that '%2F' is used when the vhost is '/'.

Regards